# evaluation line integral

Tags: calculus

i was reading special tutorial about evaluation line integral and author done following, he had to evaluate 
$$\int_{-1}^1  \cos(t)\,\sin^4(t)dt,$$
he did it by integration by part or denoted $u=\sin(t)$, $dv=\cos(t)dt$,  got
$$\int_{-1}^1 u^4dv,$$
everything is clear still here but after integration he wrote it as
$$\frac{u^5}{5},$$
i know that $\int x^adx$ is   equal $\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$ but here $u^4 dv$  could not be just $\frac{u^5}{5}$, am i correct? i think it must be 
$$u^4v-v\int u^4 dt,$$
please tell me if i am wrong

Comment: I have edited your post so that the mathematics is in LaTeX, please feel free to edit the post if I have accidentally changed your intended meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what has happened here is just that $u$ and $v$ look awfully similar, and you have mistakenly thought the computation was an [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) (where we pick factors of the integrand, and label them $u$ (yoo) and $dv$ (dee vee)), when in fact it was a [$u$-substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) (where we call some piece of the integrand $u$ (yoo), and express $du$ (dee yoo) in terms of our previous variable $t$ and its differential $dt$).

---

From user3196's explanation of the source below, here is a screenshot:
[image]

Indeed, when setting up the substitution, the "$u$" part was distinctively [serifed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif), while the "$du$" part was not. This inconsistency in the handwriting of the creator of this video is definitely the cause for the confusion.

Comment: ♦   yes maybe  i have made some mistake just here is link from youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjEvsinvtnw

Comment: ♦   yes maybe  i have made some mistake just here is link from youtube

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like a typo. This is integration by substitution, not parts, and it should be $du=\cos t\,dt$.